# Why are these characters shown in PowerPoint designer, but not in presentation?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation styled after windows 8, and I'm using the Segoe UI Light font. These characters display correctly in design mode, but not in presentation mode. Can anyone tell me why?

> 

In design mode:

[image]

In presentation mode:

[image]

Comment: Was this version of Power Point created after they made the changes to the fonts? (back in win7)  I could guess that the symbol items are in the second layer of the font, and the presenter doesn't yet understand the new fonts?  Snag it , make a pic, and go on. or use a simple symbols font?

Comment: @Psycogeek unfortunately the characters in the font were a specific talking point (albeit a very topical one) - that the default font in Windows Store Apps (Segoe) supports emojis. Powerpoint is 2010, so I suppose it might not have the latest version of the Segoe font.

Comment: I just checked that and can confirm that the version of Segoe UI Symbol that comes with Win7/PPT 2010 doesn't include these glyphs, but the version that ships with Win8/PPT 2013 does.

Answer (score 0):

I think these glyphs are in the [Segoe UI Symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx) font. Look for it in your system, and if it’s missing in the system where you’ll be presenting your slideshow, copy it over to that system.

Comment: Nope. This is on the same system, and both Segoe UI and Segoe UI symbol are installed on the system.